# Find Vout with voltage divider + pull-down resistor

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, pulldown

I have to calculate Vin (~5 V). After using the voltage divider formula the Vout value is pretty close to the value measured by a multimeter, but a little bit low.

The question is, what is the formula to calculate the Vin with the 1 MΩ resistor?

My voltage divider formula without the 1 MΩ resistor:

$$V_{\text{in}} = V_{\text{out}} \times (R_1+R_2)/R_1$$

[image]

Comment: Just calculate the equivalent resistance of the two resistors to ground, in this case 10k||1M using the standard parallel resistance formula. Then plug that into the voltage divider formula.

Comment: what a stupid question, you are right. Thank you